# LDAP filter query in multiple locations and departments

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to set up a filter in LDAP that filters out DNs for users who fit in multiple groups. In order to create a dynamic email group we query ldap using filters.

'(&(departmentNumber=3120*)(|(l=atlanta)(l=detroit)(l=new york)))'

This is close as it only returns locations with that department number. However I need to add in more departmentNumbers, and once I start doing that with this,

'(&(departmentNumber=3120*)(departmentNumber=3112*)(|(l=atlanta)(l=detroit)(l=new york)))'

I get output of all locations beyond what I've stated above and a list of groups also not stated. I've tried the inverse and the result was similar.

Thanks

Comment: So.. which users do you need to retrieve exactly (with simple words) ? And why using the wildcard character to filter numbers ? Reading from your second example I understand "users who are both in departmentNumber 3120* AND 3112*, AND who live in any cities among Atlanta, Detroit and New York.

Comment: @EricLavault I need to retrieve all users who are in those locations and work in those departments. We use the wild card because the departmentNumber is like 3120 - Business Analyst Systems